# Cross compilation using clang for target aarch64-cros-linux-gnu

Tags: c++, linux, clang, cross-compiling

Maybe I've got a silly question, but I stuck with that issue. I'm trying to do cross compilation using clang-5.0 of simple test program for target aarch64-cros-linux-gnu:

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    return 0x2;
}
```

So, when I'm running clang with the next command:

```
/home/alex/Dev/CustomToolchains/Google/clang-5.0/aarch64/usr/bin/clang --sysroot=/home/alex/Dev/CustomToolchains/Google/clang-5.0/aarch64/usr/aarch64-cros-linux-gnu -Qunused-arguments -grecord-gcc-switches -fPIE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -pie -fno-omit-frame-pointer main.cxx -o main3 -B/home/alex/Dev/CustomToolchains/Google/clang-5.0/aarch64/bin -target aarch64-cros-linux-gnu
```

I'm getting an error:

```
ld.bfd: no input files
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But when I'm removing --sysroot and -target parameters everything is ok. I have checked --sysroot path and it's exists but I'm not sure if it correct. clang docs says that this folder must contain bin, lib, include directories, but in the sysroot directory there are only next folders:

```
lib  lib64  NOTICE-eglibc  NOTICE-gdb  sbin  sys-include  usr  var
```

So, how I can specify correct toolchain path to the clang for my target triple aarch64-cros-linux-gnu? or where I can get that toolchain?

Big thanks for answers.
PS. I'm a newbie with all linux/clang/cros compilation -related staff, so I'm sorry for mistakes in my question.